# Jabra BIZ 2400 USB HeadSet doesn't output sound

Tags: usb, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I'm trying to get my Jabra BIZ 2400 USB HeadSet working on my Debian Jessie install, but I get nothing from the headphones.

I've installed Audacity to test things and it will record audio, but then plays it back at what sounds like 400% (squeaky and fast) even though it lasts the three seconds that I said "testing 1, 2, 3, testing".

From [Debian Sound on XTronics Wiki](http://wiki.xtronics.com/index.php/Debian_Sound) it suggests to do the following to install:

```
apt-get install alsa-base alsamixergui alsa-oss alsaplayer-alsa alsaplayer-common
alsaplayer-gtk alsaplayer-oss alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils bluez-alsa     
gstreamer0.10-alsa libsox-fmt-alsa jackd jackd2 jackeq jack-rack jack-stdio 
jack-tools pulseaudio-module-jack qjackctl qjackrcd slv2-jack vlc-plugin-jack 
pulseaudio pulseaudio-esound-compat pulseaudio-module-gconf 
pulseaudio-module-jack pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-module-zeroconf 
pulseaudio-utils vlc-plugin-pulse pavucontrol
```

This removes all of the 'preferred device' selection in Audio/Video Settings, replacing it with PulseAudio Sound Server, along with an additional tab 'Audio Hardware Setup', selecting Jabra BIZ 2400 USB along with Digital Stereo Output/Analog Mono Input in HARDWARE and PlayBack (Jabra BIZ 2400 USB Digital Stereo / Digital Output (S/PDIF).

But the test buttons (FRONT LEFT/RIGHT) do nothing.

Any ideas.

EDIT:
Don't know if it's relevant, but whilst looking for audio related programmes to check on my machine, I found [Jack Audio Connection Kit], it throws an error on start with the following notes:

```
22:51:00.459 Patchbay deactivated.
22:51:00.463 Statistics reset.
22:51:00.485 ALSA connection change.
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
22:51:00.492 ALSA connection graph change.
22:51:03.153 JACK is starting...
22:51:03.153 /usr/bin/jackd -dalsa -dhw:0 -r48000 -p1024 -n2
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
22:51:03.158 JACK was started with PID=7171.
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
jackdmp 1.9.10
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2014 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for playback. Falling back to capture-only mode
Cannot initialize driver
JackServer::Open failed with -1
Failed to open server
22:51:03.261 JACK was stopped
22:51:05.139 JACK is starting...
22:51:05.140 /usr/bin/jackd -dalsa -dhw:0 -r48000 -p1024 -n2
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
22:51:05.143 JACK was started with PID=7178.
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
jackdmp 1.9.10
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2014 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for playback. Falling back to capture-only mode
Cannot initialize driver
JackServer::Open failed with -1
Failed to open server
22:51:05.226 JACK was stopped
22:51:07.298 Could not connect to JACK server as client. - Overall operation failed. - Unable to connect to server. Please check the messages window for more info.
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
23:00:37.347 JACK is starting...
23:00:37.348 /usr/bin/jackd -dalsa -dhw:0 -r48000 -p1024 -n2
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
23:00:37.354 JACK was started with PID=7903.
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
jackdmp 1.9.10
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2014 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for playback. Falling back to capture-only mode
Cannot initialize driver
JackServer::Open failed with -1
Failed to open server
23:00:37.444 JACK was stopped
23:00:39.458 Could not connect to JACK server as client. - Overall operation failed. - Unable to connect to server. Please check the messages window for more info.
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceAdded(QString)
Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceRemoved(QString)
```

Comment: Does your system have front audio headers and are you using them?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a Mic/HeadPhone jack at the front of the motherboard/case?  There is, but I've not tried it previous.  Just chucked in some standard headphones and can't hear anything. I've tried via Audio/Settings on each profile/device.  Also tried in Audacity, recording via the USB HeadSet, I get a waveform, so know it has recorded, but playing back under each device results in nothing.

Comment: What happens if you plug everything into the back set of inputs?

Comment: Well something I've done in the last 24 hrs has resulted in sound from both the USB and standard headphones, so there is no room for fault finding.  I'll re-open/re-ask should I encounter this again.

Comment: Well I'm back.  The rear audio jacks don't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please post the output of `lshw -C multimedia`, `lspci`, and `lsusb` with the headphones plugged in?